# Spring @Autowired by name stops working when "Add variable attributes to class files" is deselected

Tags: java, spring, autowired

In our application we use @Autowired by name.

```
@Autowired
    public AlertSearchEndpoint(AlertSearchService alertSearchServiceImpl, AlertSearchService alertSearchServiceImpl_v4, AlertSearchService alertSearchServiceImpl_v5) {
        super();
        this.theService = alertSearchServiceImpl;
        this.theService_v4 = alertSearchServiceImpl_v4;
        this.theService_v5 = alertSearchServiceImpl_v5;...
```

This has worked fine for us but in Eclipse when we switch off a compiler setting (-g?) "Add variable attributes to generated class files" it stops working.

Our company, for some odd reason, wants to shut this off.  Is there any way to not use "@Qualifier" to fix this?  We would have a lot of code changes if we had to add this annotation.

What are my options and why would this stop working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `-g:vars` compiler option is meant to preserve the local variable names in bytecode, so that at runtime you'll be able to find `alertSearchServiceImpl`, `alertSearchServiceImpl_v4` and so on as the variable names.

When you inject multiple variables of the same type, spring needs to figure out which is which and it relies on this information if available.

Otherwise, there's no way to distinguish between the three method arguments, as only the type information will be available (and they're all of the same type) -- that is, no way other than explicitly binding a particular bean with the `@Qualifier` annotation.

One (wrong, in my opinion!) way to solve this without explicit qualifiers would be to write your own [AutowireCandidateResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AutowireCandidateResolver.html) implementation which relies on the argument position (and assumes that the first argument should be version X, the second should be version Y, and so on). But this is so error prone that I would never take a chance with it.

As for annotating all the parameters with qualifiers, even if it's a large codebase, I think you can come out with a handful of regular expressions and then "find and replace" all those parameters with their annotated versions.

Comment: When you say "by name", do you mean the variable names ? Those are nowhere to be found (since you removed the `-g:vars` flag) so it won't work. The only feasible approach IMHO would be to annotate everything with `@Qualifier` (sorry if I wasn't clear about that in the answer).

Comment: I believe my question was a bit deceptive.  It can, of course work as Spring has it on their website and it is all over the web.  I believe there are several ways to do it.  autowire="byName" is the one that is most used but I don't have xml configuration so I can't do that.  I was wondering if there was another way.  Maybe @Resource?  Anyways, thanks for the help!